# How to move all the files from one path to other except with .txt extention in JAVA?

Tags: java, file, io

I am using the below code to move zip files from one directory to another. Similarly I want to move all the directories and files except the text files present in that directory. How cam I do it?

```
Files.move(Paths.get("D:/Zip/"+zip.getName()), Paths.get("D:/Archive/"+zip.getName()));
```

Comment: look at Files.walkFileTree(path, visitor)

Comment: Look at the copy options, which is the 3rd parameter of the Files.move method.

Comment: @Files.walkFileTree is working almost in similar fashion I am still unable to figure out how to move everything else except .txt

Comment: @Nerzid I only saw two copy options in the doc REPLACE_EXISTING and ATOMIC_MOVE  first one i dont think is helpful to me second one i dont really understand also i read it and I dont think it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to filter all which does not have the extension .txt and move all other using the same code you already have in a loop. Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        final String extension = ".txt";
        final File sourceDir = new File("D:/Zip/");
        final File destinationDir = new File("D:/Archive/");
        File[] files = sourceDir.listFiles((File pathname) -> !pathname.getName().endsWith(extension));
        for(File f : files ){
            Path sourcePath      = Paths.get(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+f.getName());
            Path destinationPath = Paths.get(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+f.getName());

            try {
                Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //moving file failed.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }        
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for, if you are trying to just filter files ending in `.txt`. Here I am using the Apache Common IO library.

```
@Test
public void copyDirectory() throws IOException {
    FileFilter txtFilterer = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return !file.getName().endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("D:/Zip"), new File("C:/Archive"), txtFilterer);
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("D:/Zip"));
}
```

If you don't have access to thrid party libs you could take a look [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/). Hope that helps

Comment: This is not working because FileUtils.copyDirectory (path,path, boolean) expects boolean it throws an error moreover it will be copying directory from what I understand here I need to move the folders i.e those files and folders in src directories would be deleted

Comment: I'm using common-io 2.1 which has `copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir, FileFilter filter)` and allows for passing the `FileFilter`.  I modified the above code to show the `FileUtils.cleanDirectory` as well